# associative array : cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have to retrieve the data from a JSON file then assign it to an array. But I am getting an error

> "Cannot set property 'ref' of undefined".

Converting JSON to associative arrays or objects.

```
 var items2=[[]]; 
 $.getJSON("results.json", function( data ) {
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                if(key=="items")
                {
                    $.each(val,function(keyScd,valScd)
                    {
                        $.each(valScd,function(keyTrd,valTrd)
                    {
                        var ref=JSON.stringify(valTrd.ref).slice(1,-1);
                        var prix=JSON.stringify(valTrd.prix).slice(1,-1);
                        var taille=JSON.stringify(valTrd.taille).slice(1,-1);

                        items2[keyScd][keyTrd]["ref"]=ref;
                        items2[keyScd][keyTrd]["prix"]=prix;
                        items2[keyScd][keyTrd]["taille"]=taille;


                     });
                 });
                }
                else
                {
                        items2[key]=val;
                }
            });
        });
```

and here is my JSON

```
  {  
       "items":[  
          [  
             {  
                "ref":"cpe-zfmmpx23",
                "nomc":"1",
                "description":"yellow sofa",
                "dispo":"1",
                "prix":"300",
                "taille":"standard",
                "couleur":"jaune"
             },
             {  
                "ref":"cpe-zfmmpx23",
                "nomc":"2",
                "description":"yellow sofa",
                "dispo":"1",
                "prix":"400",
                "taille":"0.5mH,2mW",
                "couleur":"red"
             }
          ]
       ],
       "buildNumber":"fa36b5153f33240a111e6dc336a70"
    }
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ztp9mqga/  It seems to find the ref property fine.

Comment: i think its about the array

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  You are trying to treat arrays in javascript as associative arrays, which they are not.  You need to use an object instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to map the elements.  Is this what you are after?

```js
var temp = `{"items":[[{"ref":"cpe-zfmmpx23","nomc":"1","description":"yellow sofa","dispo":"1","prix":"300","taille":"standard","couleur":"jaune"},{"ref":"cpe-zfmmpx23","nomc":"2","description":"yellow sofa","dispo":"1","prix":"400","taille":"0.5mH,2mW","couleur":"red"}]],"buildNumber":"fa36b5153f33240a111e6dc336a70"}
`;

var data = JSON.parse(temp);
var items2;

if (data.items) {
  items2 = $.map(data.items, function(items) {
    return $.map(items, function(item) {
      return {
        ref: item.ref.slice(1, -1),
        prix: item.prix.slice(1, -1),
        taille: item.taille.slice(1, -1)
      };
    });
  });
}

console.log(items2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way to do it, no need for jquery there :

```js
const json = '{"items":[[{"ref":"cpe-zfmmpx23","nomc":"1","description":"yellow sofa","dispo":"1","prix":"300","taille":"standard","couleur":"jaune"},{"ref":"cpe-zfmmpx23","nomc":"2","description":"yellow sofa","dispo":"1","prix":"400","taille":"0.5mH,2mW","couleur":"red"}]],"buildNumber":"fa36b5153f33240a111e6dc336a70"}';

const newJson = JSON.parse(json);
(newJson.items).forEach((data) => {
  data.forEach((newData) => {
    console.log(newData.ref)
    });
});
```

Comment: $.getJSON auto parses the response

Comment: also, my json file is dynamic

Comment: the problem is not in parsing, it can't `set` ref to undefined